# What is the minimum wins needed to be in top 50 percent of teams in a round robin tournament?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a championship among $2n$ teams. The first round of the championship consists of a round robin tournament among all $2n$ teams. The top $n$ teams progress to the next round. Ties are resolved (by coin toss or some other parameter) only when multiple teams are fighting for the $n^{th}$ slot.

**How many wins would be "sufficient" for a team to guarantee that it reaches the next round of the championship?**

Alternatively, what are the number of wins that a team needs, so that it doesn't need to worry about the results of the games between the rest of $2n-1$ teams?

My intuition and observations:-

A semi-regular tournament on $2n$ vertices would have $n$ vertices with $n-1$ outdegree(wins) and $n$ vertices with $n$ outdegree(wins).

Thus $n-1$ wins is not sufficient.

I guess that any team with $\geq (n+1)$ wins is guaranteed a slot in the next round of the championship?

Comment: Ties can create problems.  Example four teams.  One team loses all three games.  Each of the others ends up with two wins and one loss.  (note: your statement has an error - you need to say round robin among 2n teams,)  Also your statement doesn't say how many teams go onto the next round - usually it would be half, but without that provision, my example is meaningless.

Comment: Should the phrase "among all $n$ teams" in your lead paragraph have been instead "among all $2n$ teams"?

Comment: Corrected.I agree that ties can cause problems. So in your example 2 is not sufficient but 3 wins is definitely sufficient. That is the answer I am looking for.

Thus when the round robin is among 4 teams, 3 wins is sufficient but 2 wins is not sufficient to guarantee a slot in the next round.

Comment: herb's example works for any $n$, so $n$ wins is never sufficient. It would suffice to show $n+1$ is sufficient.

Comment: Now that you have mentioned, I realised that a tournament on $2n$ vertices can be organised in such a way that $n$ teams have $n-1$ wins and $n$ teams have $n$ wins. So yes, $n-1$ is not sufficient. I wonder how to prove the second part of your claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $n+1$ is not sufficient, we'll have at least $n+1$ teams with score of at least $n+1$. That means there will have been a total of at least $(n+1)^2$ games, so we need

$$(n+1)^2 \leqslant \binom{2n}2 \implies n\geqslant 4.$$

Already for $n=4$ we can find one such configuration.

Choose $5$ of the teams and have each of them beat all of the other $3$.
Additionally, arrange these $5$ chosen teams in an oriented circle and have each of them beat the next $2$.

In this way, the $5$ chosen teams will each have a score of $5$, while the other $3$ teams will each have a score of at most $2$.

---

More generally, this can be adapted to show that no given $n+k$ works when $k$ is independent of $n$.

For a given $k$, let $n$ be sufficiently large.
We've already seen that we need $(n+k)^2 \leqslant \binom{2n}2$, but we'll see that the circle arrangement demands another condition.

Choose $n+k$ of the teams and have each of them beat all of the other $n-k$.
Additionally, arrange these $n+k$ chosen teams in an oriented circle and have each of them beat the next $2k$.
This requires that

$$2k \leqslant \frac{(n+k)-1}2 \iff 3k+1 \leqslant n$$

This ensures that $n+k$ of the teams will each have a score of at least $n+k$, while the other $n-k$ will have a score of at most $n-k-1$.

---

I'll try and make im_so_meta's answer more precise.

> **Claim:** The minimum number of wins is $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor$.

*Proof:* First, suppose that achieving a score of $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor$ did not guarantee that a team will be above the $50$th percentile.
Then there would be some win-loss configuration for which $n+1$ teams each had a score of $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor$ or more.
All of these wins would have taken at least

$$(n+1)\left(\frac{3n}2-\frac12\right) = \frac{3n^2+2n-1}2$$

games.
The other $n-1$ teams will have played another

$$\binom{n-1}2 = \frac{n^2-3n+2}2$$

games amongst themselves, for a total of $2n^2 - (n-1)/2$.
But this is more than $\binom{2n}2 = 2n^2 - n$, which is the total number of games, so no such configuration exists.
It follows that achieving a score of $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor$ does guarantee that a team will be above the $50$th percentile.

We now show that it's possible to achieve $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor - 1$ without being above the $50$th percentile.

### Case $(1):$ $n$ is even

In this case, $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor - 1 = 3n/2 - 1$.
Write this as $(n-1) + n/2$.

Choose $n+1$ of the teams and have each of them beat all of the other $n-1$.
Additionally, arrange these $n+1$ chosen teams in an oriented circle and have each of them beat the next $n/2$.
Notice that here there is no freedom, and this completely determines the games amongst these teams.

This ensures that $n+1$ of the teams will each have a score of **exactly** $(n-1) + n/2$, while the other $n-1$ teams will each have a score of at most $n-2$.

### Case $(2):$ $n$ is odd

In this case, $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor - 1 = 3n/2 -1/2 -1$.
Write this as $(n-1) + (n-1)/2$.

Choose $n+1$ of the teams and have each of them beat all of the other $n-1$.
Additionally, arrange these $n+1$ chosen teams in an oriented circle and have each of them beat the next $(n-1)/2$.
In this case, there is freedom to choose the outcome of diametrically opposite teams arranged in the circle.

This ensures that $n+1$ of the teams will each have a score of **at least** $(n-1) + (n-1)/2$, while the other $n-1$ teams will each have a score of at most $n-2$.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example. Thus $n+1$ is not always sufficient. In your example 6 wins is sufficient as at most 4 teams can have a score of 6 or higher. But my guess is that the correct answer is probably $n+c$, where $c$ is $O(1)$.

Comment: My edit addresses with some more generality these estimations.

Comment: Thanks.. those edits were quite helpful.

Comment: I have edited with what should hopefully be a clear proof of the exact minimum.

Answer (score 1):

@Fimpellizieri has already established $n+1$ is insufficient.

I claim that the minimum number of wins is $\frac{3n}{2}$. Assume for contradiction $n+1$ teams have this win total, then we already have $\frac{3n^2+3n}{2}$ wins logged in total by these teams, and the other $n-1$ teams must have at least $\binom{n-1}{2}=\frac{n^2-3n+2}{2}$ wins between them, for a total of $2n^2+1$. However, there are only $\binom{2n}{2} = 2n^2-n$ total wins! Oops. Contradiction.

Construction:
Have $n+1$ of the people all beat the other $n-1$ people. Now, we can have all of the $n+1$ people have $\frac{n+1}{2}$ wins amongst themselves by putting them on a circle and having them beat the next $\frac{n+1}{2}$ people in a certain direction, plus or minus a half (half of the people have plus, half have minus) (credit to @Fimpellizieri for the idea). For those who have minus a half, then we have $\frac{3n}{2}-1$ wins, and all of these people tie.

I realize this answer glosses over the cases whether $n$ is even or odd, but the answer is either $\frac{3n}{2}$ or $\frac{3n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$.

Thanks for @Fimpellizieri for pointing out that I accidentally found the equality case, botched the arithmetic, and somehow thought it was the answer.

Comment: I think the general direction is good, but this definitely needs to be tidied up. In my example with $n=4$ we see that $3n/2 -1 = 5$ is not enough, and that in fact $n+1$ teams do achieve that win total.

Comment: Oops. I seem to have botched my arithmetic, I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: @Fimpellizieri is this better?

Comment: Thanks to both @Fimpellizieri and im_so_meta_even_this_acronym    ... The proof shows that $3n/2$ is sufficient whereas $3n/2-1$ may not be sufficient as shown by the example. I guess we can resolve the problem to be closed?

Comment: @Vk1: $\frac{3n}{2}-1$ is not sufficient but anything more is.  So you could say the answer is $\frac{3n}{2}-\frac12$, or if you prefer integers then $\left\lceil \frac{3n}{2}-\frac12 \right\rceil$ or equivalently $\left\lfloor\frac{3n}{2} \right\rfloor$